# How to skip a bootstrapper or ignore fail in Windows 8?

Tags: .net, windows-8, wix, bootstrapper

I have a WiX installer and a number of bootstrappers. We recently added SQL LocalDB support and found we needed to package .Net 4.0.2 to get it to work. I am now testing on Windows 8, and find that this patch fails and isn't actually needed for this OS.

However, my installer fails because .Net 4.0.2 fails. I am trying to find a way of either skipping this patch in Windows 8 or just ignoring a fail for this patch?

I have "`InstallConditions`" and "`ExitCodes`" in my `package.xml`, but I don't know how to change these to achieve either:

1. don't try to install when OS is windows 8, or
2. try, but ignore a fail and continue to the next step

Any ideas?

Comment: I may have cracked it with this command: <BypassIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="ValueGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="602"/> However, I don't know if the value should be 602 or 6.0.2 or something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured this out by trial and error, and I'll put the solution here for others who might find it useful. The problem was I was using `ValueGreaterThanOrEqualTo` and it should have been `VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo`

This will skip for Windows 8

`<BypassIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="6.2"/>`

This will skip for Windows 7 and 8

`<BypassIf Property="VersionNT" Compare="VersionGreaterThanOrEqualTo" Value="6.1"/>`

Comment: 6.3 is Windows 8.1 if you later also need to skip this.