# WIX Bootstrapper Takes Too Long To Begin

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I have a working WIX Bootstrapper that does install the software I need it to install.  However On Windows 8 At least, there is a 16 minute period where it appears to do nothing.  Looking at TaskManager, I see no processes taking resources from the Bootstrapper (that I can tell).  For some reason about 15 minutes into it it will just finish the install:

```
[0E6C:0E90][2014-01-24T13:49:45]i299: Plan complete, result: 0x0
[0E6C:0E90][2014-01-24T13:49:45]i300: Apply begin
[0E04:0DD8][2014-01-24T14:05:35]i360: Creating a system restore point.
[0E04:0DD8][2014-01-24T14:05:50]i361: Created a system restore point.
```

Any ideas as to why this is taking so long, after the log says "Apply begin"?

Note:  Behavior does not happen on XP or Vista, Or 7.  I think it has something to do with "pausing" Windows updates during installs.  Does anybody know anything about that?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you tested it on OS before Windows 8 e.g. Windows 7, Vista, XP?
Are you using Custom Bootstrapper code or default UI ?
Better share your Burn Wixology here.

Comment: Hi Farrukh, I have updated my question to reflect yours.  Answer:  Yes on XP, Vista, 7 it does not take 15 minutes between "Apply Begin" and the Restore Point" step.  I think it might have something to do with the way Windows 8 pauses Windows updates during certain types of installs.  Not sure, haven't found an answer yet.  And I am using the WixStandardBootstrapperApplication HyperlinkLicense (LicenseUrl is blank)

Comment: @JasonHughes Have you ruled out the possibility that the 15-minute pause is specific to that machine? (read: have you tried it on another win 8 machine?) Follow-up: Is it an option to install 8.1 and see if the issue goes away?

Comment: Hi Jason, please could you update the thread with a short explanation of what fix worked? Just for reference when people see the thread.

Comment: Hi Glytzhkof, I marked your answer as the answer by mistake.  Problem still exists. Multiple windows 8 machines. Still investigating, I will update when I find something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never could find a parameter or condition in my installer that would cause this.  However the effect went away when I used insignia to sign my wix projects (MSIs and a bootstraper).  Prior to that I had been using the signtool by itself to do the signing.

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a **timeout** of some sort. I assume there are multiple MSI files, and some of them may be tagged with a launch condition (look in the **LaunchCondition table**) which disallows installation on Windows 8? Maybe worth a check at least. Try launching each MSI manually in sequence and see if you receive any error messages. There may also be missing runtimes such as .NET, C++, Crystal Reports or similar. Often the MSI will display an appropriate error message to tell you what is wrong.

In case you find nothing when launching each MSI, you should make **verbose log files** for all of them so there is something to work with for debugging. If you are unfamiliar with **msiexec.exe** (Windows Installer Command Line Interface), you can use the tool described in this thread: [installation using msi.exec open help options every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164005/installation-using-msi-exec-open-help-options-every-time/22166685#22166685) . It should be easy to enable verbose logging using that tool.

Also check this thread: [How to skip a bootstrapper or ignore fail in Windows 8?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18919110/how-to-skip-a-bootstrapper-or-ignore-fail-in-windows-8)

And the documentation might be useful: http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/howtos/redistributables_and_install_checks/