# Silent Installer with custom selection

Tags: installshield

Currently my installer is need user to choose which type of setting they want to use when install. Lets say got setting A,B and C.

If want to make this in silent installer. Is there any method can use?

I'm using install shield.

Answer (score 0):

You can set **PUBLIC PROPERTIES** inside the MSI file from the msiexec.exe command line like this:

```
msiexec /i test.msi /qn TESTPROPERTY=1
```

These properties are the ones you have hooked up to values input in the GUI. They are now set by the command line (or defaults are used from the Property table) and the entire GUI section of the MSI gets skipped on install.

Here is a sample showing how INSTALLDIR is hooked up to the GUI (Wise for Windows Installer shown, same concept in Installshield and other MSI tools):

[image: Image description]

To play around with **complex command lines** for msiexec.exe I always recommend this nifty tool from Altiris: [http://www2.wise.com/filelib/WICLB.exe](http://web.archive.org/web/20140402194132/http://www2.wise.com/filelib/WICLB.exe) - **broken link, resurrected from Wayback Machine**, seeing as the tool was freeware I assume that is legal - (see a screenshot of it here: [installation using msi.exec open help options every time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22164005/installation-using-msi-exec-open-help-options-every-time/22166685#22166685)). Please run the download by [virustotal.com](http://www.virustotal.com) for safety.